# c++ template variadic function undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

TestTempB.h

```
#ifndef TESTTEMPB_H_
#define TESTTEMPB_H_
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace ddl_lib {

class TestTempB {
public:
    TestTempB();
    virtual ~TestTempB();
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandB(const string&, const uint32_t*, Args ...);
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandA(const string&, Args ...);
};

} /* namespace ddl_lib */

#endif /* TESTTEMPB_H_ */
```

TestTempB.cpp

```
#include "TestTempB.h"
#include "TestTempA.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace ddl_lib {

TestTempB::TestTempB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

TestTempB::~TestTempB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

template<class ... Args>
void TestTempB::callCommandB(const string& cmdName, const uint32_t* cmdSn, Args ... params) {
    cout << cmdName << endl;
}
template<class ... Args>
void TestTempB::callCommandA(const string& cmdName, Args ... params) {
    callCommandB(cmdName, NULL, params...);
}
} /* namespace ddl_lib */
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestTempB.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ddl_lib;

int main() {
    string aa="15615";
    bool ccc=false;
    TestTempB b;
    b.callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc);//undefined reference to `void ddl_lib::TestTempB::callCommandA<std::string*, bool*>(std::string const&, std::string*, bool*)'
}
```

I'm using the  variadic-template.
Why the gcc can't deduced the real func?
When the callCommandA and callCommandB in the main file,it works just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestTempB.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ddl_lib;
template<class ... Args>
void callCommandB(const string& cmdName, const uint32_t* cmdSn, Args ... params) {
    cout << cmdName << endl;
}
template<class ... Args>
void callCommandA(const string& cmdName, Args ... params) {
    callCommandB(cmdName, NULL, params...);
}
int main() {
    string aa = "15615";
    bool ccc = false;
    callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc); //no erro
}
```

Why and how could I fix it?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Either use explicit instantiation or make the definitions visible to the translation units that use them.

Comment: In other words, declare and implement the templates in the header files, not cpp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **CANNOT** put template function into `.cpp`. you must put it into `.h` because compiler must know what the template is when specializing it.

your first main file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "TestTempB.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace ddl_lib;

int main() {
    string aa="15615";
    bool ccc=false;
    TestTempB b;
    b.callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc);//undefined reference to `void ddl_lib::TestTempB::callCommandA<std::string*, bool*>(std::string const&, std::string*, bool*)'
}
```

is equal to

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace ddl_lib {

class TestTempB {
public:
    TestTempB();
    virtual ~TestTempB();
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandB(const string&, const uint32_t*, Args ...);
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandA(const string&, Args ...);
};

} /* namespace ddl_lib */
using namespace ddl_lib;

int main() {
    string aa="15615";
    bool ccc=false;
    TestTempB b;
    b.callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc);//undefined reference to `void ddl_lib::TestTempB::callCommandA<std::string*, bool*>(std::string const&, std::string*, bool*)'
}
```

Now think as if you were the compiler. you're trying to compile `b.callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc)`. You have to *specialize* the template, but you do *not* know what it exactly is. To compile it, you have to know that, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace ddl_lib {

class TestTempB {
public:
    TestTempB();
    virtual ~TestTempB();
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandB(const string&, const uint32_t*, Args ...);
    template<class ... Args>
    void callCommandA(const string&, Args ...);
};

template<class ... Args>
void TestTempB::callCommandB(const string& cmdName, const uint32_t* cmdSn, Args ... params) {
    cout << cmdName << endl;
}
template<class ... Args>
void TestTempB::callCommandA(const string& cmdName, Args ... params) {
    callCommandB(cmdName, NULL, params...);
}

} /* namespace ddl_lib */
using namespace ddl_lib;

int main() {
    string aa="15615";
    bool ccc=false;
    TestTempB b;
    b.callCommandA("name", &aa, &ccc);//undefined reference to `void ddl_lib::TestTempB::callCommandA<std::string*, bool*>(std::string const&, std::string*, bool*)'
}
```

Now you *do* know what `callCommandA` is, then you can specialize and compile it.